# Using Maya Wrap deformers on Curves

Tags: maya, curve

I have a joint chain controlled by a Spline IK and a dense curve.

I'd like to keep that curve as is, but use a simpler curve (same length, but less CV's) to control the complex curve.

I'm using the Wrap deformer, but the results are not what I'd expect. The dense curve doesn't smoothly follow the simple curve.

Here's a pic:

[image]

I've fiddled with the options but they haven't helped. Is there another deformer or method I should try?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a programming question. You should post elsewhere like [cgtalk](http://forums.cgsociety.org/).
You'll probably get much better results using a wire deformer (Create Deformers menu->Wire Tool). It's made to deform other objects based from curves.